# Set scores to database after passing the exam in ASP.NetCore 3.1 MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

My Question Model

```
 public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Title { get; set; }
    
    public string A { get; set; }

    public string B { get; set; }

    public string C { get; set; }

    public string D { get; set; }

    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }

    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Answer Answer { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my view.cshtml

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <div>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)

                        <input type="radio" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.A)" id="A" name="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.Id)" class="rb" />
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.A)
                        <input type="radio" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.B)" id="B" name="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.Id)" class="rb" />
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.B)
                        <input type="radio" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.C)" id="C" name="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.Id)" class="rb" />
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.C)
                        <input type="radio" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.D)" id="D" name="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.Id)" class="rb" />
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.D)
                    </div>

                }
```

So how can I can compare the user answer with my correct answer and then give a score and save it to the database?

and this is my table that should store the score:

```
public class StraintTest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string  FatherName { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
    public int Grammar { get; set; }
    public int Vocabulary { get; set; }
    public int Reading { get; set; }
    public int Listening { get; set; }
    public int Writing { get; set; }
    public int Speaking { get; set; }
    public string Exam_Date { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public int ProgramId { get; set; }
    public virtual Program Program { get; set; }
}
```

this is the StriantTest Service :

```
 public int AddStraintTest(StraintTestViewModel test)
    {
        var newStriant = new StraintTest()
        {
            Name = test.Name,
            LastName = test.LastName,
            FatherName = test.FatherName,
            Contact = test.Contact,
            Cost = test.Cost,
            Exam_Date = test.Exam_Date,
            Grammar = test.Grammar,
            Listening = test.Listening,
            Speaking = test.Speaking,
            Writing = test.Writing,
            Reading = test.Reading,
            ProgramId = test.ProgramId.HasValue ? test.ProgramId.Value:1,
            Score = test.Score

        };
        _context.Add(newStriant);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return newStriant.Id;
        
    }
```

this is StrainTest Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(StraintTestViewModel straintTest)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int id = _istraintTest.AddStraintTest(straintTest);
            if (id > 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Create));
            }
        }
        ViewBag.Program = new SelectList(_iprogram.GetProgram(), "Id", "Name");

        return View();
    }
```

this is my View, when the start exam button clicked, it should take the Id of this field and show the questions and after submitting the question the score field should update and show the score that the student got from exam.
[image]

and this is my setting score operation:

```
public IActionResult TakeExam(int straintTestId)
    {
        var data = _iquestion.ShowQuestion();
        return View(data);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult TakeExam(IEnumerable<Question> Questions, int straintTestId)
    {
        ExamCheck examCheck;
        int score = 0;
        if(Questions != null)
        {
            foreach(Question Q in Questions)
            {
                examCheck = new ExamCheck();
                examCheck.StriantTestId = straintTestId;
                examCheck.QuestionID = Q.Id;
                examCheck.CorrectAnswer = Q.AnswerId;
                if(Q.SelectAnswer != null)
                {
                    examCheck.StudentAnswer = (int)Q.SelectAnswer;
                }
                else
                {
                    examCheck.StudentAnswer = 0;
                }
                _context.ExamChecks.Add(examCheck);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                if(Q.SelectAnswer == Q.AnswerId)
                {
                    score += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        StraintTest straintTest = new StraintTest();
        straintTest.Id = straintTestId;
        straintTest.Score = score;

        _context.StraintTests.Add(straintTest);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return View(straintTest);
    }
```

when I click it shows the questions but it doesn't set score...!

it would really please if someone help me obviously !!!

Comment: A small side note, your database first code is not defining indexes, accessing your data will be via table scan. have a look at the database using SQL profiling and see look at the where statements and update your model

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't get what exactly you mean...?

Comment: my bad I guess, have a look at  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes, when ever you would think you need to filter on a data field you need an index, in your case ProgramId and fields like Contact as I guess you search by it

Comment: but there I made  a field as programId

Comment: did EF generate an index? have a look at your database execution plans and see if all is going well https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/sql-server/operations.

Comment: yes that is all okay

Answer (score 1):

I wrote simple test code for you. You can check this and implement yourself.
This is my question class :

```
public class Question
    {
        public string Tittle { get; set; }
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
        public string C { get; set; }
        public string D { get; set; }
        public bool OptA { get; set; }
        public bool OptB { get; set; }
        public bool OptC { get; set; }
        public bool OptD { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is controller Get Action. I created random questions dont mind that.

```
public IActionResult test() {
            List<Question> list = new List<Question>() { 
                new Question { Tittle = "Asadasadasa", A = "asasas", B = "basasasasas", C = "casadsdfadsad", D = "dasadsdsd" },
                new Question { Tittle = "Asadasadasa", A = "asasas", B = "basasasasas", C = "casadsdfadsad", D = "dasadsdsd" },
                new Question { Tittle = "Asadasadasa", A = "asasas", B = "basasasasas", C = "casadsdfadsad", D = "dasadsdsd" },
                new Question { Tittle = "Asadasadasa", A = "asasas", B = "basasasasas", C = "casadsdfadsad", D = "dasadsdsd" },
                new Question { Tittle = "Asadasadasa", A = "asasas", B = "basasasasas", C = "casadsdfadsad", D = "dasadsdsd" },
                new Question { Tittle = "Asadasadasa", A = "asasas", B = "basasasasas", C = "casadsdfadsad", D = "dasadsdsd" },
            };
            return View(list);
        }
```

after that this is my view page. I used checkbox for input this allow multi slect but you can use option group for that.I forget to add options text but dont mind that either :).

```
@model List<EpsilonMFALanguage.Help.Question> 


<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form action="@Url.Action("test","Home")" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                @for (int i=0;i<Model.Count;i++)
                {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Tittle" />
                    <label id="lbl_@i" class="col-md-12" asp-for="@i">@Model[i].Tittle</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="@i" asp-for="@Model[i].OptA" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="@i" asp-for="@Model[i].OptB" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="@i" asp-for="@Model[i].OptC" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="@i" asp-for="@Model[i].OptD" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                }
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

this way when user solve the test and click submit it goes to my test Post action.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult test(List<Question> list) {
            return Json("");
        }
```

when I debug the post action this is the result. You can see wihch option was selected.
[image: posted list item]

Comment: First of all thanks for your help.  but the problem is that during making questions, admin should choose which option is the answer and then when a user take the exam we should compare the user answer with the option that the admin chosen as a correct answer, then if the user answer and correct answer are the same we should give them score.

Comment: After user submit the question form you have all question with selected answers. You can check there if question is correct or not  and give score. Just need the correct answers from your db or where do you store the answers. Get them and compare.